# localStorage["something"] vs localStorage.something

Tags: javascript, local-storage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript property access: dot notation vs. brackets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets)

I'm a total newbie to chrome extensions.
I know Java but Javascript is something entirely different.

I would like to ask what is the difference between `localStorage["something"]` and `localStorage.something`?

The square bracket vs dot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no difference. In fact, there is no difference between the two syntaxes in JavaScript as a whole:

```
someObj.someProp === somObj["someProp"];
```

The only difference is that certain characters are valid in a string and not in a dot-property name:

```
someObj["some-prop"] // valid
someObj.some-prop // this is actually the value of `someObj.some` minus the value of `prop`
```

Note that both of these methods of storing values in `localStorage` are also the same as using the `.getItem` and `.setItem` methods.  According to the [W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/):

> Each Storage object provides access to a list of key/value pairs, which are sometimes called **items**.

These *items* are accessible and mutable via the object property of the same name or by refering to them by name using `.getItem` and `.setItem`.  The only difference is that the functions can be overwritten to provide wrappering, e.g., to JSON-ify the object before storage:

```
localStorage.setItem = function(key, val) {
    localStorage[key] = JSON.stringify(val);
}
```

Comment: `someObj.someProp === somObj["someProp"];` Not true, if the value is `NaN`. TROLOLOLO `:P`

Comment: @ŠimeVidas And neither true when using `var someObj={};Object.defineProperty(someObj,'someProp',{get:function(){return{};}});`. `NaN` is more likely to occur than this one, though ;)

Comment: @ŠimeVidas And while we're being entirely precise, the dot and bracket notations on `localStorage` differ slightly from `set`/`getItem`: property access cannot persistently store values in keys that share the name of native properties on `localStorage`, whereas function access can. The line `localStorage.setItem = "foo"` does not cause persistent storage, whereas `localStorage.setItem("setItem", "foo")` does. `:P`