# localStorage.property vs localStorage['property']

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, local-storage, developer-tools, web-storage

Is there a difference between writing `localStorage['key'] = value` or `localStorage.setItem('key', value)`?

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12096169/localstoragesomething-vs-localstorage-something) marked as duplicate but within Developer Tools the behavior of both notations is different: the bracket notation does not seem to serialize to a string.

For instance:

```
> localStorage['key'] = [1,2,3]
[1, 2, 3]
> localStorage.setItem('other', [4,5,6])
undefined
> localStorage.key
[1, 2, 3]
> localStorage.other
"4,5,6"
> localStorage.key.length
3
> localStorage.other.length
5
```

Can anyone explain that difference in behavior? Can I use the bracket notation and forget about always serializing to JSON?

Comment: Maybe you should use a different title then if you don't want to be closed as an exact duplicate of that question you mention.

Comment: This behavior might have something to do with the name of the property (i.e. 'key'). And I don't think it's a duplicate.

Comment: Indeed it has, see my answer. Still, you should [edit] the title of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, see [localStorage - use getItem/setItem functions or access object directly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13092715/1048572) - you can use properties the same way as `getItem`/`setItem`. Both ways will stringify the values automatically.

Unless…
you are using one of the [predefined methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#Storage)' names, like of `.key()`. That is calling for trouble.

- Opera and Firefox will store the value in the localStorage, and return the string when the `.key` is subsequently accessed.
- Chrome, on the other hand, will just overwrite the method on the `localStorage` object. No stringification happens, and you just will get the object you did put there. It will not be stored.

```
> localStorage.key
function(){ … }
> localStorage.key = [1,2,3]
[1,2,3] // the rvalue

Opera> localStorage.key
"1,2,3"
Opera> localStorage.length
1

Chrome> localStorage.key
[1,2,3]
Chrome> localStorage.length
0
```